# Mozilla Rhino: Default JavaScript Compliance Level

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

to execute JavaScript in Rhino one has to create an execution context for the script. The constructor of the [Context class](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.java) uses the JavaScript compliance level `VERSION_DEFAULT.`

```
protected Context(ContextFactory factory) {
    if(factory == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("factory == null");
    }
    this.factory = factory;
    **setLanguageVersion(VERSION_DEFAULT);**
    optimizationLevel = codegenClass != null ? 0 : -1;
    maximumInterpreterStackDepth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

As I cannot find a mapping of `VERSION_DEFAULT` to any of the actual `VERSION_XXX` constants in the API, I'm wondering which JavaScript compliance level VERSION_DEFAULT is.
The release note of Rhino 1.7R1 (*ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_Rhino_1.7R1) states that one has to specify the JavaScript version explicitly, but it does not mention which version is used when `Context.setLanguageVersion()` is omitted.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on the Mozilla Rhino mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Having had a look through most of the Rhino code, it looks like most of the testing against language version is negative testing, e.g.

```
if (getLanguageVersion() != Context.VERSION_1_2) {
  return paramCount;
}
```

VERSION_DEFAULT is defined as '0', so the one place where it looks like it would need to be set as 1.7 is to support the "let" and "yield" keywords because of this code from TokenStream:

```
if ((result == Token.LET || result == Token.YIELD) && 
  parser.compilerEnv.getLanguageVersion() 
    < Context.VERSION_1_7)
{
  // LET and YIELD are tokens only in 1.7 and later
  result = Token.NAME;
}
```